# get latest three values by date

Tags: java, list, sorting, date, treemap

Hello I have the following scenario:

I have 2 Lists:

```
final List<FirstDO>  firstList;
final List<SecondDO> secondList;
```

Both DO's (FirstDO, SecondDO) contain a String field and a date field and
other fields which are different from each other.
Let's assume we have these values:

First List contains 2 FirstD0-Objects with these values:

```
First Object:
    1. String field = "test"
    2. Date field = 01.10.2017.
    .....

Second Object:
    1. String field = "test2"
    2. Date field = 05.10.2017.
    .....
```

Second List contains 2 SecondDO-Objects with these values:

```
First Object:
    1. String field = "test3"
    2. Date field = 06.10.2017.
    .....

Second Object:
    1. String field = "test"
    2. Date field = 07.10.2017.
    .....

Third Object:
    1. String field = "test4"
    2. Date field = 02.10.2017.
     .....
```

Now I need to iterate both lists and take the latest three field-values from both lists sort by the date(descending). So these would be then: test, test2 and test3. You may have noticed that "test" was contained in both lists, but since in the second list the date field (07.10.2017) is bigger than "test4" (02.10.2017)..I need to take "test".

So I always need to retrieve up to max three field values sorted by the date(descending). In other words, If i combine both lists, I need to take the latest three values.

I tried to use a TreeMap like this:

```
        final Map<Date, String> myTreeMap= new TreeMap<Date, String>();
```

And then just iterate through both lists and insert in this map and then it should by automatically sorted by the date, since date implements the comparable interface, however it overwrites if i put values with the same date, since a map cannout have duplicate keys. I don't know how it would be the best way to solve this problem.

Comment: Note that the `Date` class is **legacy** now and should not be used anymore. Instead use the new API located inside the package `java.time`.

Comment: The `Date` class is part of the troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. For a date-only value without time-of-day, use `LocalDate` class.

Answer (score 0):

## `Comparable`

I would have both of your data object's implement a common interface that shows that they both have a date and have this interface implement [`java.lang.Comparable`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Something like this.

```
interface hasDateAndData implements Comparable<hasDateAndData>{
    abstact public Date getDate();
    abstract public String getString();

    @Override
    public int compareTo(hasDateAndData otherDD){
         int compareValue = getDate().compareTo(otherDD.getDate());
         if (compareValue == 0) {
             //You need to define what order objects come in if there dates are equal
         } else {
             return compareValue;
         }
    }
}
```

Then you can add all of the items from both of your lists to a new list of this type, sort this list, and take the first three values.

```
List<hasDateAndData> combinedList = new ArrayList<hasDateAndData>();
combinedList.addAll(firstList);
combinedList.addAll(secondList);
combinedList.sort();
```

Comment: I just wanted to mention that my objects (FirstDo and SecondDo) are not similar, so this means that they have also other fields which are different from each other, but they both have a date and a string field, i will update my question

Comment: I didn't assume that your objects were similar at all.  I suggested that you change them to both implement a common interface that knows about their date and string fields.

Comment: ok thx you very much for your answer. I will try analyze your solution. I am just not very familiar with rhe comparable interface, so my firstDo and SecondDo implememt this interface and the methods and just return the date and the string value right?

Comment: Your code is broken. An interface implementing an interface? Abstract fields? I'm pretty sure you mean an abstract class here, and if that would be the case, then your `I didn't assume that your objects were similar at all` statement would be problematic, as two classes extending a common class would make then inherently similar.